# Get c++ commands in cmd

Tags: cmd

I am a Windows 8 user.

How would I get command such as make and g++ in my cmd window? I got javac stuff from downloading jdk. How to do for c++? Tanks

Comment: The program would need to be compiled down to some sort of executable that your OS knows how to handle and include the directory of that executable in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Can't you ask your friend to explain how it works? He clearly knows. This is a basic *teach me how to use my computer* question and isn't really programming-related. (Mentioning *c++ or java or c* doesn't magically make it a programming question.) The question you're asking is *How do I run a program from a command prompt?*, which is an OS/computer use question.

Comment: That was too harsh for me :( I guess I'll need to learn how to use my computer then

Answer (score 0):

To achieve similar results, you would need to compile code into an executable of some sort (ie, `C:\Dev\myfile.exe`) and add the directory of where the file resides into your system `PATH` environment variable (ie, `C:\Dev`) or change the directory of your command prompt to that directory via `cd C:\Dev`.

Then you can invoke your executable directly in the command prompt,

```
C:\>myfile       # assuming the directory is setup in PATH environment variable
```

or

```
C:\Dev\> myfile  # navigate to folder and invoke executable directly
```

[How to Run a Program](http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Program-on-Command-Prompt)